# Is it possible that define pdf attach file in django framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

We use

```
Title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
```

For char fields.
Is it possible simply use PdfField or FileField in model.py for uploading pdf files?
For example:

```
Title    = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
Document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

I do not want to use form and... Extra codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `FileExtensionValidator` for done this.

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

class YourModel(models.Model):
    pdf_field = models.FileField(upload_to="pdfs/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=["pdf"])
```